# CakePHP 3 updating data in the join table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm having trouble updating existing data in my join table. Here it goes...

I have 2 models SalesOrders and Products that have a belongsToMany association through LineItems.

```
products
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

sales_orders
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order_number | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

line_items
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sales_order_id | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| product_id     | int(11) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| qty            | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Creating a new sales order works as expected. I can add multiples products and quantities to a sales order on the add new sales order page. All the correct data is added to the join table.

The problem I'm having is when I try to edit an existing sales order. For example, I want to change the quantity of a certain line item from 5 to 2. I open the edit page for the sales order I wish to modify, change the quantity on the desired line item, and submit the form. The form submits successfully but the join table is not updated. This seems like pretty basic functionality that I can't get working. All of my code was baked with a few small modifications.

SalesOrdersTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Products', [
    'foreignKey' => 'sales_order_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'product_id',
    'through' => 'LineItems',
]);
```

ProductsTable:

```
$this->belongsToMany('SalesOrders', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'sales_order_id',
    'through' => 'LineItems',
]);
```

LineItemsTable:

```
$this->belongsTo('Products', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('SalesOrders', [
    'foreignKey' => 'sales_order_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

SalesOrdersController edit:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $salesOrder = $this->SalesOrders->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Products']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $salesOrder = $this->SalesOrders->patchEntity($salesOrder, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->SalesOrders->save($salesOrder)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The sales order has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The sales order could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $products = $this->SalesOrders->Products->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('salesOrder', 'products'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['salesOrder']);
}
```

SalesOrders template edit.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->input('order_number');
echo $this->Form->input('products.0.id', [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $products
]);
echo $this->Form->input('products.0._joinData.qty');
```

The SalesOrder entity looks like this when submitting the form to change the quantity from 5 to 2.

```
object(App\Model\Entity\SalesOrder) {

    'id' => (int) 1,
    'order_number' => 'SO1111',
    'products' => [
        (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Product) {

            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Acme Widget 1',
            '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\LineItem) {

                'id' => (int) 1,
                'product_id' => (int) 1,
                'sales_order_id' => (int) 1,
                'qty' => (int) 2,
                '[new]' => false,
                '[accessible]' => [
                    '*' => true
                ],
                '[dirty]' => [
                    'qty' => true
                ],
                '[original]' => [
                    'qty' => (int) 5
                ],
                '[virtual]' => [],
                '[errors]' => [],
                '[invalid]' => [],
                '[repository]' => 'LineItems'

            },
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true,
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [
                '_joinData' => true
            ],
            '[original]' => [
                '_joinData' => object(App\Model\Entity\LineItem) {

                    'id' => (int) 1,
                    'product_id' => (int) 1,
                    'sales_order_id' => (int) 1,
                    'qty' => (int) 2,
                    '[new]' => false,
                    '[accessible]' => [
                        '*' => true
                    ],
                    '[dirty]' => [
                        'qty' => true
                    ],
                    '[original]' => [
                        'qty' => (int) 5
                    ],
                    '[virtual]' => [],
                    '[errors]' => [],
                    '[invalid]' => [],
                    '[repository]' => 'LineItems'

                }
            ],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Products'

        }
    ],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'SalesOrders'

}
```

As you can see the dirty property on the SalesOrder is empty. It's not picking up that the Products _joinData has been modified.

If I add $salesOrders->dirty('products', true); just before save() is called then join table gets updated. While this works, and I could write some logic to handle the update this way, I feel there is better/proper way to do this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was a cake bug in 3.3 that wasn't resolved until the 3.3.2 release. Once I updated everything worked as expected. [github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/9276](http://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/9276)